# Redis::CommandError: ERR max number of clients reached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, resque

I am receiving the above error and trying to get more insight. My app has 3 types of background jobs and about 100 users so nothing too heavy.

My goal is to be able to process multiple background jobs at the same time (so if 10 users perform the same job, they don't need to wait for each other job to finish before starting).

I'm confused as to how many dynos I need, how many workers I need, how many redis connections I need. What's the difference between all these things?

My current setup has:

1 x professional web dyno
1 x professional scheduler dyno
3 x professional worker dyno

and my procfile:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
scheduler: bundle exec rake resque:scheduler
worker: env TERM_CHILD=1 QUEUE='*' COUNT='3' bundle exec rake resque:workers
```

And I am getting the error:

> Redis::CommandError: ERR max number of clients reached

I am just surprised because it seems like what I'm trying to achieve is pretty simple.

Comment: did you solve this later? Facing a similar issue.